# JDA - How do I get an EmbedMessage as an Object?

Tags: discord-jda

How do I get an embed message? I want to get the footer of an Embed Message I already posted into the chat. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends how you're pulling the message:

If you're using an reaction or edit event (Depending on how you're pulling the message), you could possibly be using:

```java
    @Override
    public void onGuildMessageReactionAdd(@Nonnull GuildMessageReactionAddEvent event) {
        event.getChannel().retrieveMessageById(event.getMessageId()).queue(p -> {
            if (p.getEmbeds().size() > 0) {
                if (p.getEmbeds().get(0) != null) {
                    p.getEmbeds().get(0).getFooter().getText();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Keep in mind that there are 3 components in the [MessageEmbed#Footer](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/MessageEmbed.Footer.html)
[Click here for components picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eh1lT.png)

You have [`getText()`](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/MessageEmbed.Footer.html#getText()), [`getProxyIconUrl()`](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/MessageEmbed.Footer.html#getProxyIconUrl()) and [`getText()`](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/MessageEmbed.Footer.html#getText()).

In your case, you'd need the `getText()`. To pull the text from an already existing embed.

Answer (score 0):

The same way you get any other message. Embeds are just one component of a message and you can get a list of embeds using [Message#getEmbeds](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/Message.html#getEmbeds()).

To get a message you can use [retrieveMessageById](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/MessageChannel.html#retrieveMessageById(java.lang.String)).